# How to fix mobile menu disappearing issue on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an issue on my WordPress website here: https://nazim.skypage.in/

On mobile when you toggle the menu open it immediately disappears as soon as you start to scroll down. The really weird thing is that it doesn't happen in the Chrome inspector, I can scroll up and down the menu just fine.

Any guidance would be very helpful. Thank you!

Here is my HTML source code:

```
<nav class="clearfix" id='cssmenu'>
<div id="head-mobile"></div>
<div class="button">Menu</div>
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-10"><a href="https://nazim.skypage.in/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-237" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-237"><a href="https://example.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-313" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-313"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-317" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-317"><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-314" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-314"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-318" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-318"><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-315" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-315"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-316"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

Here is menu CSS:

```
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

nav .button {
    display: none
}

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu #head-mobile,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0
}

#cssmenu #head-mobile {
    display: none
}

#cssmenu {
    float: right;
    padding: .5% 0
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
    float: left
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #42474e;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a:hover {
    color: #265683
}

ul#menu-menu {
    float: right
}

#cssmenu ul li.active a,
#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a {
    color: #265683
}

#cssmenu ul li.active,
#cssmenu ul li.active:hover,
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub.active:hover,
#cssmenu>ul>li:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #265683;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background .3s ease;
    transition: background .3s ease
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:after,
#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:before {
    display: block;
    background: #185387;
    content: '';
    position: absolute
}

#cssmenu ul ul li,
#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:before {
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a {
    padding-right: 30px
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:after {
    top: 24px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:before {
    top: 21px;
    right: 14px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    transition: all .25s ease
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub:hover>a:before {
    top: 23px;
    height: 0
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
    height: 0;
    background: #333;
    transition: all .25s ease
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a:after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    content: ''
}

#cssmenu li:hover>ul {
    left: auto
}

#cssmenu li:hover>ul>li {
    height: 35px
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    margin-left: 100%;
    top: 0
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, .15);
    padding: 11px 15px;
    width: 190px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 400
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child>a {
    border-bottom: 0
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover,
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a {
    color: #fff
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a:after {
    top: 16px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a:before {
    top: 13px;
    right: 14px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease
}

#cssmenu ul ul>li.has-sub:hover>a:before {
    top: 17px;
    height: 0
}

#cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover,
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover {
    background: #363636
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a {
    border-left: 1px solid #333
}

#cssmenu>ul ul>li.has-sub>ul>li.active>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>ul>li.active>a {
    border-top: 1px solid #333
}


@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    #cssmenu ul,
    #cssmenu ul ul>li.has-sub>a:after,
    #cssmenu ul ul>li.has-sub>a:before,
    #cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:after,
    #cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a:before {
        display: none
    }
    #cssmenu,
    #cssmenu ul,
    nav {
        width: 100%
    }
    #cssmenu ul li {
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px solid #eee
    }
    #cssmenu li:hover>ul>li,
    #cssmenu ul ul li {
        height: auto
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a,
    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 0
    }
    #cssmenu>ul>li {
        float: none
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        padding-left: 25px;
        color: #ddd;
        background: 0 0
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li {
        background: #333!important
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover {
        background: #363636!important
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
        padding-left: 35px
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.active>a,
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a {
        color: #fff
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul,
    #cssmenu ul ul ul {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left
    }
    #cssmenu #head-mobile {
        display: block;
        color: #ddd;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 700
    }
    nav .button {
        width: 94%;
        padding: 3%;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 12399994;
        display: block;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        background: #f2b74c;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 100%
    }
    nav .button:after,
    nav .button:before {
        right: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        content: ''
    }
    nav .button:after {
        top: 22px;
        height: 4px;
        border-top: 2px solid #fff;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fff
    }
    nav .button:before {
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
        transition: all .3s ease;
        top: 16px;
        height: 2px;
        background: #fff
    }
    nav .button.menu-opened:after {
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
        transition: all .3s ease;
        top: 23px;
        border: 0;
        height: 2px;
        width: 19px;
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg)
    }
    nav .button.menu-opened:before {
        top: 23px;
        background: #fff;
        width: 19px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg)
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        border-left: 1px solid #eee;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
        background: #262626
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
        height: 38px;
        width: 38px
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 23px;
        right: 21px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 2px;
        display: block;
        background: #ddd;
        content: ''
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
        top: 17px;
        right: 15px
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
        background: #fff
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 24px;
        display: block;
        width: 2px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #ddd;
        content: ''
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
        top: 14px;
        right: 18px
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
        display: none
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a {
        border-left: none
    }
    #cssmenu>ul ul>li.has-sub>ul>li.active>a,
    #cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>ul>li.active>a {
        border-top: none
    }
```

Here are my menu js codes:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>(function($) {
$.fn.menumaker = function(options) {  
 var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
   format: "dropdown",
   sticky: false
 }, options);
 return this.each(function() {
   $(this).find(".button").on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
     var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
     if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
       mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
     }
     else {
       mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
       if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
         mainmenu.find('ul').show();
       }
     }
   });
   cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
multiTg = function() {
     cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
     cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
       if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
         $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
       else {
         $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
     });
   };
   if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
   else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
   if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
resizeFix = function() {
  var mediasize = 1000;
     if ($( window ).width() > mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').show();
     }
     if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
     }
   };
   resizeFix();
   return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
 });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   format: "multitoggle"
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: I checked your site but there is no such issue. Can you explain it by adding images

Comment: It's your wordpress theme, check how to manage it with wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything in your code, so this is just a wild guess. But it sounds like a javascript issue. I think the menu (and it's styles) are being reset when the user is resizing the window. Most mobile browser hide the url bar when you scroll, which fires the window resize event in javascript.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fix it.?

Comment: Yes, It's hiding when resizing the screen size. I have inspected it in chrome with mobile responsive option and then try to resize the window, in result open menu got hide.

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: I have updated my question with menu js codes. Please have a look and help me to fix the menu disappear issue on scrolling / resizing window.

Answer (score 0):

For me SKeurentjes's wild guess was true.
What worked for me:

- get rid of all resize events in js
- duplicate menu's html, one under class eg. .menu.mobile, other under .menu.desktop. Each one is not/displayed by media query.
- then bind different js behavior to .menu and .desktop classes.